# How to send composing extension notification using flex's XIFF API?

Tags: apache-flex, openfire, flex-spark, xiff

I'm using the Xiff API in flex to connect to my XMPP server.
and ill send message successfully but ill not get typing notification .

right now i am get following message

```
<message type="normal" id="m_1" to="abc@localhost/localhost"
    from="xyz@lcoalhost/xyz">
    <composing xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates"/>
</message>
```

but i want following .

```
<message type="normal" id="m_1" to="abc@localhost/localhost"
    from="xyz@lcoalhost/xyz">
    <x xmlns="jabber:x:event">
    <composing/>
</message>
```

how i can get please help about this .

Comment: Hi user1697238, you mean you want to add extension to your jabber packet. right?

Comment: Yes, right. I have developed a flex application, and now I want to show "user is typing.." for that I need to send composing notification. I am sending notification (xml packet 1 in question), but spark can't show "user is typing" notification,
and second xml packet is being sent from spark when I type anything in spark.

Comment: ok. you are doing this with jabber protocol. which intermediate server are you using?

Comment: I am using openfire as my intermediate server. 
Basically I want to send composing notification from spark to flex and flex to spark.